# smoothing raster layer stack using R

Tags: raster, r, modis, smoothing

I'm trying to do smoothing for .tif stack layer of 331 bands. 
I used this code in R :

```
setwd("D:\\")    

raster_dir <-   "D:\\Modis VI quality\\"

VI <- brick(paste(raster_dir,"laikipia_VI_quality.tif", sep=""))

timeInfo <- orgTime(VI, nDays=16, begin="2001001", end="2015145")

system.time(whittaker.raster(vi,timeInfo=timeInfo,lambda=5000,overwrite="true"))
```

But, it is not working and giving,

> Warning messages: 1: In min.default(numeric(0), na.rm = FALSE) :   no
>   non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf 2: In
>   max.default(numeric(0), na.rm = FALSE) :   no non-missing arguments to
>   max; returning -Inf Errors: Error: dir.create(path, recursive = TRUE,
>   showWarnings = showWarnings) is not TRUE

Any advice or help writing the correct code please?

Comment: Welcome to GIS StackExchange! Please consider [editing](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/193944/edit) your question with [markdown](http://gis.stackexchange.com/editing-help) to make code samples easier to identify and read within the question.

Answer (score 1):

A possible reason might be that `vi` (which you pass on to `whittaker.raster`) does not exist. Please provide the error message in order to clarify this issue.

Note that **MODIS** has been moved to [GitHub](https://github.com/MatMatt/MODIS) a while ago. You can easily install the latest versions via

- (stable version)
  `devtools::install_github("MatMatt/MODIS")`
- (development version)
  `devtools::install_github("MatMatt/MODIS", ref = "develop")`.

However, I noticed that there is something wrong with the most recent version of `whittaker.raster`. In my case, it finishes without throwing an error, but the smoothed rasters hold integer values only (i.e., 0, 1, 2, ...). A possible, yet quite inconvenient workaround until this issue is solved would be to temporarily install an older version of **MODIS** (you can download [MODIS_0.10-18.tar.gz](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ws4g8mr6ujxfahk/MODIS_0.10-18.tar.gz?dl=0) from my Dropbox) and employ the `whittaker.raster` algorithm included therein.

Here is some sample code that works on my machine

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
(...)
```

using the 'develop' version from above and, temporarily, **MODIS_0.10-18**. The Kenyan shapefile I am using for demonstration purposes (since you did not provide any sample data) originates from [GADM](http://www.gadm.org/) and can easily be downloaded via `getData` from **raster**. I omitted the usage of `orgTime` since (i) the required information is automatically extracted from the supplied 'vi' argument during `whittaker.raster` and (ii) I did not want to modify the default 'pillow' size (see `?orgTime`).

```
## install and load 'MODIS' package
devtools::install_github("MatMatt/MODIS", ref = "develop")
library(MODIS)

## set 'MODIS' options
if (!dir.exists("data")) 
  dir.create("data")

MODISoptions(localArcPath = "data/MODIS_ARC", outProj = "+init=epsg:21037",
             outDirPath = "data/MODIS_ARC/PROCESSED", 
             MODISserverOrder = c("LPDAAC", "LAADS"))

## reference extent (kenya)
shp <- getData(country = "KEN", level = 0, path = "data")
shp <- spTransform(shp, CRS = CRS("+init=epsg:21037"))

## download tiles
collection <- getCollection("MYD13A2", forceCheck = TRUE)

runGdal("MYD13A2", collection = collection, job = "MYD13A2.006", 
        tileH = 21, tileV = 9, SDSstring = "101000000000", 
        begin = "2004001", end = "2005365")

## pre-processing (import, crop, mask)
lst <- lapply(c("NDVI", "VI_Quality"), function(i) {
  # list and import available files
  fls <- list.files(paste0(getOption("MODIS_outDirPath"), "/MYD13A2.006"), 
                    pattern = paste0(i, ".tif$"), full.names = TRUE)

  rst <- stack(fls)

  # crop reference extent and, if required, apply scaling factor
  rst_crp <- crop(rst, shp)     

  if (i == "NDVI") 
    rst_crp <- rst_crp * 0.0001

  # return processed images
  return(rst_crp)
})

## install and load 'MODIS' version 0.10-18 (assuming that the older version of 
## 'MODIS' is located inside your current working directory)
detach("package:MODIS", unload = TRUE)
install.packages("MODIS_0.10-18.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
library(MODIS)

## apply whittaker smoother
rst_wht <- whittaker.raster(vi = lst[[1]], w = lst[[2]], overwrite = TRUE)
```

---

[image: spplot]